# Out of memory (allocated 1834483712) (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)

Tags: php

```
public function update(){
    $query = "UPDATE `stock` SET `status`= 'expired'";
    $data =[$this->status];
    return $this->update($query, $data); //Error Line 
}
```

I have also used:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

I Can anyone give me solution to this.

Comment: this function has infinite recursion: `$this->update($query, $data)` call `public function update()` that call `$this->update($query, $data)`

Comment: So, what can I do to now ? Is there any solution to this ?

Comment: @sarinaByanjankar you need to change the code and remove the  infinite recursion.. only solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

your code has infinite recursion

```
public function update(){                               // <--
    $query = "UPDATE `stock` SET `status`= 'expired'";  //    |
    $data =[$this->status];                             //    |                     
    return $this->update($query, $data);                //  --
}
```

the only solution is to change the code and remove the infinite recursion.

eg. rename `public function update()` into `public function updateDb()`:

```
public function updateDb(){                             
    $query = "UPDATE `stock` SET `status`= 'expired'";  
    $data =[$this->status];                                                
    return $this->update($query, $data);                
}
```

after, refractoring your code and call `updateDb()` instead of `update()`